# How to setup Mocha test file to avoid Sequelize loading errors?

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

*Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: servings* is the error that I'm receiving when running tests.

**routes.js**

```
db.food.create(body).then(food => {
  db.serving.create({portion, description}).then(serving => {
    food.addServings(serving).then( () => {
      return food.reload();
    }).then( () => {
      res.json(food);
    });
  });
}, e => {
  res.status(400).json(e);
});
```

**server.test.js**

```
    const should = require('chai').should();
    const expect = require('chai').expect;
    const supertest = require('supertest');

    const {app} = require('./../server.js');

    describe('Food', () => {
      describe('POST /foods', () => {
        it('should create a new food', (done) => {
         const egg = {
        "portion": 50,
        "name": "large egg",
        "description": "large egg",
        "calories": 80,
        "protein": 8,
        "carbs": 0,
        "fat": 3
      };

  supertest(app)
    .post('/foods')
    .send(egg)
    .expect(200)
    .end((err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }

      expect(res.body).to.be.an('object');
      expect(res.body).to.have.property('carbs');
      expect(res.body).to.not.have.property('portion');
      done();
    });
});
```

**server.js**

```
    db.sequelize.sync({force: true}).then(function() {
        app.listen(port, function() {
            console.log(`Express running on port# ${port}`);
        });
    });

    let routes = require('./routes')(app, db);

    module.exports = {app};
```

I think the problem arises because express and the database do not get loaded by the time that the tests start to run. The subsequent tests are fine, it's just the first one that does not write to the database properly.

Is there a way that I could change the test file or my server.js so that it waits until the database loads?

I've searched but there only seems to be mongoose specific stuff, and I'm using sequelize.

**EDIT - Solved**

```
    db.sequelize.sync({force: true}).then(function() {
        app.listen(port, function() {
            console.log(`Express running on port# ${port}`);

            let routes = require('./routes')(app, db);


            app.emit('serverStarted');
        });
    });
```

Then do this before the test.

```
    before(done => {
      app.on('serverStarted', () => {
        done();
      });
    });
```

Comment: If you solved your problem on your own + think it might be useful for others, you should create answer as well. Do not include answer yo your question!

Comment: If you don't think it'll be useful for anybody else, just delete the question to reduce noise on SO.

Answer (score 1):

**server.js**

```
        db.sequelize.sync({force: true}).then(function() {
            app.listen(port, function() {
                console.log(`Express running on port# ${port}`);

                let routes = require('./routes')(app, db);


                app.emit('serverStarted');
            });
        });
```

Then do this before the test in the testfile.

```
before(done => {
  app.on('serverStarted', () => {
    done();
  });
});
```